# Why does msvc let me do this but not gcc / g++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

In msvc, I have functions like this and it builds but in gcc it doesnt like it.

```
void classname::a(std::string &text)
{
    stdStringFromClass = text;
}

void classname::b(char *text)
{
    a(std::string(text));
}
```

The issue here is in the &, gcc I think is worried that since I just created that std::string, that passing by reference is risky, so it does not build, but msvc doesnt even warn me.

Why is this incorrect c++ to gcc I keep hearing that msvc is stricter than gcc.

Thanks

**The error**

```
AguiWidgetBase.cpp: In member function ‘void AguiWidgetBase::setText(char*)’:
AguiWidgetBase.cpp:91:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘AguiWidgetBase::setText(std::string)’
AguiWidgetBase.cpp:80:6: note: candidates are: void AguiWidgetBase::setText(std::string&)
AguiWidgetBase.cpp:88:6: note:                 void AguiWidgetBase::setText(char*)
```

would this be okay?

```
void classname::a(std::string &text)
{
    stdStringFromClass = text;
}

void classname::b(char *text)
{
   std::string k = text;
    a(k);
}
```

Comment: Need more context. What's the error you get, what is "stdStringFromClass", etc.

Comment: stdStringFromClass is a std::string

Comment: MSVC is not more strict than gcc, that seems rather backwards to me. The error is that a temporary cannot be bound to a non-const reference. However, it's tough to tell you a solution when you've shown very little code. Do you need to modify the parameter? If not, make it a const-reference. What's the point of having a `char*` (should be `const char*`) overload along with a `std::string` overload? `std::string` can be implicitly constructed from a `const char*`.

Comment: Really? Can you have a class named `class`?

Comment: @GMan: Thanks, I knew that. I was amazed by the question text where `class` is consistently used as a class name. Since SO is archived, I thought that it is not a good example to archive. My comment was supposed to be humor :(, although I did not put the smiley :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why Visual studio allows you to compile this, but you can't pass a reference to an anonymous object.

Edit: Its ok for const reference, cause you can pass the temporary object as reference, just being able to modify it doesn't make sense. That's why we have rvalue references in C++0x.

Edit2: To your edit, yes that would fix the problem, or just take a const reference as parameter in the `a()` method, you don't seem to modify the parameter.

Comment: Oh, you should see some of the other stuff msvc lets me do :p

Comment: const references work, though. The error I get with some guessing is: "str.cpp:11: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::string&’ from a temporary of type ‘std::string’"

Answer (score 6):

I think this is an old compiler extension that Visual Studio supported since way back then, but it is kept around in modern Visual C++ for compatibility. Try disabling compiler extensions (`/Za` flag) and see what happens.

Alternatively, use the `/W4` flag to get maximum warnings, and it should complain:

> warning C4239: nonstandard extension used

On GCC I get the const reference error:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::string&’ from a temporary of type ‘std::string’

Answer (score 3):

I believe someone else said this first, but passing a reference to an anonymous object is illegal. Visual C++ is weird. To fix it, try something like this:

```
void class::a(const std::string &text)
{
    stdStringFromClass = text;
}

void class::b(const char *text)
{
    a(std::string(text));
}
```

BTW, I assume your class name is not actually 'class', and you're just using that as a placeholder, because

```
class class {
    // ...
};
```

stuff is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual error message I can only guess: class is a reserved keyword and you should name your class differently, this is not a valid method definition:

```
void class::a(std::string &text) { ... }
```

EDIT: the problem is in passing the anonymous reference, as others have pointed out. You can just ignore this answer now.